# Make custom xml from javabean

Tags: java, xml, eclipselink, javabeans, moxy

I wants to make xml from javabean like below:

```
        <tag2>message</tag2>
        <tag3>message</tag3>
        <tag4 id='UNIQUE MT ID 1'>MOBILE No.</tag4>
```

I tried below code in javabean:

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = {"tag2", "tag3", "tag4"})
 public class newBean {

@XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<String> tag2;

@XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<String> tag3;

@XmlElement(required = true)
    private List<String> tag4;

@XmlPath("tag4/@id")
    private List<String> id;

public  List<String> getTag2() {
    return tag2;
}

public void setTag2(List<String> tag2) {
    this.tag2 = tag2;
}

public List<String> gettag4() {
    return tag4;
}

public void settag4(List<String> tag4) {
    this.tag4 = tag4;
}

public List<String> getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(List<String> identifier) {
    this.id = identifier;
}

public  List<String> gettag3() {
    return tag3;
}

public void settag3(List<String> tag3) {
    this.tag3 = tag3;
}
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
    Errorcom.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of           IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    Property id is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
            at private java.util.List model.newBean.id
            at model.newBean
```

Please help me.I am using @XmlPath tag and generating error.I searched alot and found that @XmlPath usage is same as above i used but still getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

### About `@XmlPath`

`@XmlPath` is a EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) extension and requires that you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

**Valid Use Case #1**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = { "tag4", "id" })
public class newBean {

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    String tag4;

    @XmlPath("tag4/@id")
    String id;

}
```

**Valid Use Case #2**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = { "tag4", "id" })
public class newBean {

    @XmlPath("tag4/@id")
    List<String> id;

}
```

**Invalid Use Case**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = { "tag4", "id" })
public class newBean {

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    List<String> tag4;

    @XmlPath("tag4/@id")
    List<String> id;

}
```

### Mapping Your Use Case

You could introduce an object that corresponds to the `tag4` element that has two properties corresponding to the `id` attribute and text.  This would work with any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.

**newBean**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "name", propOrder = { "tag4", "id" })
public class newBean {

    List<Tag4> tag4;

}
```

**Tag4**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tag4 {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it create below when i am adding id in propOrder on the @XmlType.   <tag2>message</tag2>
            <tag3>message</tag3>
            <tag4>message</tag4>
            <id>123</id>

Comment: @CodeProgram - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.